# Are Memory Crystals new?

Tags: final-fantasy-record-keeper

Going into this game i figured that every character was capped at level 100, standard RPG format. however when i entered into a FFIX event to get Vivi and Garnet the Elite stages offered rewards for getting Memory Crystals which apparently allowed one to pass the Level Cap. there was also an event to get Tidas's Memory Crystal.

Now i went into an event a while ago and got Vanille, i looked at all the other prizes to see if it was worth my time trying to get them at my current level and didn't see any Memory Crystal for Vanille.

So i am wondering, are these Memory Crystals a new feature? if so how do i get Memory Crystals for characters i got in previous events (ie. Vanille) and for the characters unlocked playing the normal levels? (ie. Cloud, Rydia etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Memory Crystals are new for the global client. They have been around for quite a while in the Japanese client. The only memory crystals that have been released so far are Tidus, Wakka, Garnet, and Vivi. More memory crystals will be added to the game as events and dungeon updates occur.

In order to obtain a memory crystal for a particular character, you need to fulfill a certain condition. So far, memory crystals appear to be given for completing a particular stage. For Vivi and Garnet, there are two stages in the Princess of Alexandria event that award their memory crystals upon completion. In tomorrow's dungeon update (6/16/15), the Bard memory crystal, should be a reward for completing the Base Missile elite dungeon in the FFVIII realm. In fact, the dungeon update should allow us to obtain the following memory crystals: Tyro, Cloud, Bard, Black Mage, Ranger, White Mage, Kain, and Rydia.

Note: You can obtain a memory crystal at any time, however, you cannot use it on a character unless they have reached the level cap (in this case, 50). When you use a memory crystal, you will raise the level cap for that character to 65, unlock the ability to use record materia (additional perk that is equippable on a character), obtain the character's first record materia, and unlock the ability to obtain their second record materia (fulfill special condition with character in the party).